# How to incorporate the changed API for an already created collection consisting of several test scripts?

Tags: api, postman

Let' say I have a collection called "Test" which has 2 API and each API consists of 8-10 test cases having different sets of data although with the same API call. 
Now if 1 API got changed from dev end.. and to take the import from Swagger or some other files or program for the changed API to update in my collection. How the presently created collection "Test" would not be affect and the changed API will be incorporated in the collection ?. 
So far when try to import , it either ask for creating a duplicate of the whole set or replace with the present one. In both the cases my test cases with different data in the collection will be lost. Please let us know if there is any functionality or any work around

Comment: To my knowledge there is no functionality. if you don't have too much tests and do not need to do this too often, the best is to get the duplicate then remove the old test. In my case, to ease some user's work I intend to implement a python script that compares the reference swagger and the new one then indicates which tests are different, added or to remove ... but it's not straightforward

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was also thinking the same as there is no such straightforward mechanism available. I think the same is true for SOAP UI tool. If you have any idea on this. It would be helpful if you could please throw some light into it.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet with SOAP UI, this could be a problem as well :(